# does initWithNibName need to be released

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I use initWithNibName to load detail views.  I was just thinking do these things need to be released at all?  init is basically adding  a retain count of 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Mel:

Yes you need to release them.

A Part from Apple's Doumentation:

**You own any object you create**

**You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).**

But as such it has nothing to do with `initWithNibName` but it is related to four words which allocate the memory that is 'mutableCopy','copy', 'retain' and 'alloc'. So hope it is clear to you now.

`init` keyword just initializes an object. Allocation of memory is done though `alloc` or `retain` or `copy` or `mutableCopy` keyword

And the retain count of 1 that you are talking about is because of the `alloc` keyword, not the `initWithNibName`.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Of course, you also create an object with, eg, [NSMutableArray array], but you don't need to `release` it.  The distinction is between objects that are created with just `retain` (alloc/copy/et al) and those that are created with an additional `autorelease` (pretty much everything else).

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Read [this section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1). Anything starting with `init...` gives you an object you own.

Comment: Nit: "init..." doesn't create the object.  "alloc" creates the object, and "init..." initializes it, and I'm fairly sure (but not certain) that it's "alloc" that retains the object.  But (except in really strange circumstances) you can't have one without the other, so your statement is close enough to the truth for most purposes.

Comment: OK, I changed "creates"  to "gives you". Contented?

Answer (score 2):

The section in question:

> **You own any object you create**
>   You create an object using a method
>   whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for
>   example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).
>
> **You can take ownership of an object using retain**
>   A received object is normally guaranteed to remain valid within the method it was received
>   in, and that method may also safely return the object to its invoker.
>   [...]
>
> **When you no longer need it, you must relinquish ownership of an object
>   you own**
>   You relinquish ownership of an object by sending it a release
>   message or an autorelease message. In Cocoa terminology, relinquishing
>   ownership of an object is therefore typically referred to as
>   “releasing” an object.
>
> You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own This is
>   just corollary of the previous policy rules, stated explicitly.

Generally, though, you should avoid thinking in terms of retain counts and focus on *ownership*. If you own it, it's up to you to release it.